# Dataweave Date Formatting with Timezone

Tags: date, datetime, dataweave, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to format a date to the following format, UTC with the Timezone Offset:

Expected:
`2021-01-20T21:00:00-06:00`

Actual:
`2021-01-20T00:00:00-06:00`

Code:

```
var arrivedAt = "2021-01-20T15:00:00"
var timezone = "America/Chicago"

var finalDateTime = (((arrivedAt as Date) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00"}) as LocalDateTime ++ (timezone as String))
```

I'm assuming it's due to the "00:00:00" in the format but when I try using "HH" or "hh" I'm receiivng errors.

Comment: Why do you expect the hour to be 21 after taking -06:00 from the UTC time? Seems to be incorrect.

Comment: If the time was 3:00pm/15:00 CST, wouldn't this be 9:00pm/21:00 UTC? UTC is 6 hours ahead of CST?

Comment: Your question appears to ask to convert from UTC to the "america/chicago" timezone. If that is not correct please update it to be more specific. For example the expected output timezone is -06.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is that it's documented here https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone

This example code assigns a timezone to the original date and then shift it to UTC

```
var arrivedAt = "2021-01-20T15:00:00"
var timezone = "America/Chicago"
var dateWithTimezone = (arrivedAt as LocalDateTime) ++ "America/Chicago"
// dateWithTimezone = "2021-01-20T15:00:00-06:00"
var dateOnUTC = dateWithTimezone >> "UTC"
// dateOnUTC = "2021-01-20T21:00:00Z"
--- 
dateOnUTC as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"}
```

NOTE: I'm not sure if the expected value is right on the question or if the example date is wrong.

Comment: arrivedAt is in local time (America/Chicago).

Comment: Ok, so `arrivedAt` is a LocalDateTime (means it has no timezone). To convert it to Datetime, you need to add the right timezone, in this case `-06:00`. That should be it for your use case. `2021-01-20T21:00:00-06:00` means that it's 9 PM on Chicago. `2021-01-20T21:00:00Z` is UTC and means it's 5 PM on Chicago.

Comment: Sorry, `2021-01-20T21:00:00Z` is UTC (on ISO format) and means it's 3 PM in Chicago.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the incorrect data types and trying to do the date transformations as strings. That is highly unadvised. The errors are probably because a Date doesn't has a time neither a timezone.

One alternative is to treat the date time as a DateTime, to be able to use the timezone features:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var arrivedAt = "2021-01-20T15:00:00"
var timezone = "America/Chicago"

var finalDateTime = (arrivedAt as DateTime >> timezone ) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"}
---
finalDateTime
```

Output

```
"2021-01-20T09:00:00-0600"
```

Actually the correct hour seems 9 instead of 21 as in your expected result. Maybe you did the timezone transformation the other way around?